# error while verifying my contract on Ropsten network

Tags: solidity, javascript, hardhat

I have deployed my contract to Ropsten network, using hardhat. But when I want to verify it, I get this error which is about etherscan API-key:

```
Error in plugin @nomiclabs/hardhat-etherscan: Please provide an Etherscan API token via 
hardhat config. For example:

{
  ...
 etherscan: {
    apiKey: {
      ropsten: 'your API key'
    }
  }
}

See https://etherscan.io/apis
```

I've checked my API and its fresh and does not have problem. Also I have used .env file for my private data and this is my hardhat.config.js code:

```
module.exports = {
  solidity: "0.8.10",
  networks: {
    ropsten: {
      url: `https://ropsten.infura.io/v3/${process.env.INFURA_API_KEY}`,
      accounts: [process.env.PRI_KEY],
    },
  },
  etherscan: {
    apikey : process.env.ETHERSCAN_API_KEY,
  },
};
```

so where is the problem, why can I not verify that contract?

Comment: try  etherscan: {
    apikey : { ropsten: process.env.ETHERSCAN_API_KEY  }
  }

Comment: @MajdTL I tried it, does not work.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? Having the same issue after confirming all ENV variables are present, as expected. Issue persists even when hard-coding in the config file.

Comment: @alphazwest yes. i added my solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think that the error was in this command:
`env $(cat .env) npx hardhat verify --network rinkeby 0x86...` .

i tried to import my env variables in hardhat,config.js like this:

```
const ETH_API_KEY = process.env.ETHERSCAN_API_KEY;
const INF_API_KEY = process.env.INFURA_API_KEY;
const PRIVATE_KEY = process.env.PRI_KEY;
```

and also changed my module.exports:

```
module.exports = {
  solidity: "0.8.12",
  networks: {
    rinkeby: {
      url: `https://rinkeby.infura.io/v3/${INF_API_KEY}`,
      accounts: [`0x${PRIVATE_KEY}`],
    }
  },
  etherscan: {
    apiKey: ETH_API_KEY    
  }
};
```

and then i used this command to verify the contract:

```
npx hardhat verify --network rinkeby 0x86...
```

and the error solved.
this solution also worked for ropsten and other networks.